# background working updating script not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I created an background working script, that updates my database table on a condition.

Here is my **main script**:

```
<?php
require_once('conn.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '" . $_COOKIE['username'] . "'";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);

if($row['ehp'] > $row['required_ehp']) {
    // The 'ehp' column is greater than 'required_php'
    $calc = $row['ehp'] % $row['required_ehp'];
    $new = $row['required_ehp'] * 12;
    $new_lvl = $row['level'] + 1;

    $query2 = "UPDATE user set level = '$new_lvl', ehp = '$calc', required_ehp = '$new'";
    mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
    echo 'query successful';

} else {
    echo 'query unsuccessful' . mysql_error();   
}
 echo $row['ehp'] % $row['required_ehp'];
echo   $row['required_ehp'];

?>
```

The error message I am getting from this script is:

> query unsuccessful
>   Warning: Division by zero in H:\AppServ\www\sp\userlevel.php on line 21

I don't know what's is wrong. Please help me.

Here is [the database column's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aRSj.png).

Comment: Bad idea #1 > WHERE id = '" . $_COOKIE['username'] . "' are u sure that the sql is with correct syntax ?

Comment: What are you gonna update? The where is missing? What record are you gonna update?

Comment: Is this site live? Oh please! Tell us the login URL!

Comment: @Svetlio yes i am sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found out my mistake it was just that in `id` in my database, I was searching for the `username` column. Sorry to bother you all.

Answer (score 0):

Since you see `query unsuccessful`, that means that the line `if($row['ehp'] > $row['required_ehp'])` is `false`.

In the line `echo 'query unsuccessful' . mysql_error();` there is no mysql error, therefore you only see the line `query unsuccessful`.

Also you get the devision by 0 warning. This is caused by the line `echo $row['ehp'] % $row['required_ehp'];`. It seems `$row['required_ehp']` is `0`.

Summing this all up, perhaps the data you expect to be in `$row` is not what you are expecting. Maybe the cookie data is incorrect?

**Also, putting the cookie data straight into the query is a horrible idea, and easily to hack.**